# Null reference exception deep inside TelerikDropDownList

Tags: c#, blazor, telerik-blazor

I'm getting a null reference exception deep inside Telerik's Blazor DropDownList component and I can't spot why. Here's a page that demonstrates the error.

```
@page  "/DropDown"

@using Telerik.Blazor.Components

@if (UserDataSource != null)
{
    <TelerikDropDownList Data="@UserDataSource" TextField="@nameof(User.Name)" ValueField="@nameof(User.UserNumber)" @bind-Value="SelectedUser" />
}

@code {
    public long SelectedUser { get; set; }

    protected List<User> UserDataSource { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        base.OnInitialized();
        UserDataSource = new List<User>
        {
                new User { Name = "User 1", UserNumber = 1 },
                new User { Name = "User 2", UserNumber = 2 },
                new User { Name = "User 3", UserNumber = 3 }
        };
        SelectedUser = 1;
    }

    public class User
    {
        public long UserNumber;
        public string Name;
    }
}
```

The stack trace of the error is here. What's making this hard to fix is that the error happens very far away from any of my code.

```
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CastHelpers.Unbox(Void* toTypeHnd, Object obj)
   at Telerik.Blazor.Components.TelerikDropDownList`2.<MapSelectedItem>b__101_1(ListDataItem item)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.TryGetFirst[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate, Boolean& found)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
   at Telerik.Blazor.Components.TelerikDropDownList`2.<MapSelectedItem>d__101.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Telerik.Blazor.Components.TelerikDropDownList`2.<OnParametersSetAsync>d__77.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.<CallStateHasChangedOnAsyncCompletion>d__22.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.<RunInitAndSetParametersAsync>d__20.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Telerik.Blazor.Components.Common.TelerikSelectBase`2.<SetParametersAsync>d__178.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.HtmlRenderer.HandleException(Exception exception)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.AddToPendingTasks(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.ComponentState.SetDirectParameters(ParameterView parameters)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.InitializeNewComponentFrame(DiffContext& diffContext, Int32 frameIndex)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.InitializeNewSubtree(DiffContext& diffContext, Int32 frameIndex)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.InsertNewFrame(DiffContext& diffContext, Int32 newFrameIndex)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.AppendDiffEntriesForRange(DiffContext& diffContext, Int32 oldStartIndex, Int32 oldEndIndexExcl, Int32 newStartIndex, Int32 newEndIndexExcl)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.ComputeDiff(Renderer renderer, RenderBatchBuilder batchBuilder, Int32 componentId, ArrayRange`1 oldTree, ArrayRange`1 newTree)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.ComponentState.RenderIntoBatch(RenderBatchBuilder batchBuilder, RenderFragment renderFragment)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.RenderInExistingBatch(RenderQueueEntry renderQueueEntry)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.ProcessRenderQueue()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.HtmlRenderer.HandleException(Exception exception)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.ProcessRenderQueue()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.ProcessPendingRender()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.AddToRenderQueue(Int32 componentId, RenderFragment renderFragment)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.StateHasChanged()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.CallOnParametersSetAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.<RunInitAndSetParametersAsync>d__20.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.HtmlRenderer.HandleException(Exception exception)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.AddToPendingTasks(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.ComponentState.SetDirectParameters(ParameterView parameters)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.<RenderRootComponentAsync>d__29.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.HtmlRenderer.<CreateInitialRenderAsync>d__17.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.HtmlRenderer.<RenderComponentAsync>d__8.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.RendererSynchronizationContext.<>c__11`1.<<InvokeAsync>b__11_0>d.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.StaticComponentRenderer.<PrerenderComponentAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ComponentRenderer.<PrerenderedServerComponentAsync>d__8.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ComponentRenderer.<RenderComponentAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers.ComponentTagHelper.<ProcessAsync>d__21.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Runtime.TagHelpers.TagHelperRunner.<<RunAsync>g__Awaited|0_0>d.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at TelerikSandbox.Pages.Pages__Host.<<ExecuteAsync>b__14_1>d.MoveNext() in C:\source\hans\TelerikSandbox\TelerikSandbox\Pages\_Host.cshtml:line 22
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your model to this:

```
public class User
{
    public long UserNumber { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```